# SQL Compare GUI works, but command line gives problems

Tags: sql, sqlcompare

I recently purchased SQL compare 7.1 pro for the command line capabilities. We have been using the GUI version with no problems for some time now. I am trying to exclude items from the sync, however its not working.

I am using the .scp file created from the GUI. My syntax is:
SQLCompare.exe /pr:"file.scp" /v sync >> Log.txt.
I have tried the /exclude:Function and /exclude:user to exclude certain items and it still syncs them.

The only way that I could get it to exclude anything is if I went into the .scp file and changed the "DeselectItem" that I was excluding, to "SelectItem" and then do the exclude. This seems backwards because if someone opens the GUI to make a change, all of the checked/un-checked items will be backwards.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted RedGate's support? They are usually very good.